# Why can I make a symbolic link in the target directory but not in the source directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, symbolic-link

Suppose I have a directory `foo`, another directory `foo/bar`, and finally a file `foo/bar/foobar`.

Here's the quirk:

- If I am in the directory `foo` and type `ln -s bar/foobar .` it creates a working symlink.
- If I am in the directory `foo/bar` and type `ln -s foobar ../` it creates a symlink to the symlink itself, which makes it broken.

I suppose it is somehow related to absolute path vs relative path since `ln -s "pwd"/specavg_Pr1_ID15_20160201.fits "pwd"/../` (not actually `"` but `` ` ``, but it has a rendering issue) works perfectly.

What I don't understand is, if it were `cp` or other commands it'd do as what I've expected. But were it not, it would've made huge disasters. What is the difference here, and is there a good habit to ensure my commands reference files correctly? (without referencing with full path all the time...)

Answer (score 0):

From [`man 1 ln`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html):

> Symbolic links can hold arbitrary text; if later resolved, a relative link is interpreted in relation to its parent directory.

When you do `ln -s foobar ../` in `foo/bar`, the arbitrary text is `foobar` and the parent directory of the link is `../`, i.e. `foo/`. Therefore the new `foo/foobar` symlink resolves `foobar` in `foo` and points to itself.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/837935/432690):

> […] GNU coreutils' `ln` (>= 8.16) support the `--relative` (or `-r`) option which means you can call `ln -s` with 2 absolute or relative (in respect to your working directory) paths and it will figure out the correct relative path that has to be written to the symlink.

If your `ln` is the GNU `ln` then try this in `foo/bar`:

```
ln -sr foobar ../
```

and the resulting symlink will be `foobar -> bar/foobar`. Note the resulting arbitrary text is not what you used in the command. It's what `ln -r` figured out.

In general (especially if you cannot use `-r` of the GNU `ln`) you need to remember how the symlink works: arbitrary text, interpretation in relation to its parent directory. Without `-r` the arbitrary text comes verbatim from the relevant command line argument.